# YCSB for Cassandra 3.0 Benchmarking

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-2.0, ycsb

I have a cassandra ubuntu visual cluster and need to benchmark it.

I try to do it with yahoo's ycsb (without use of maven if possible).
I use cassandra 3.0.1 but I cant find a suitbale version of ycsb.

I dont want to change to an oldest version of cassandra (ycsb latest cassandra-binding is for cassandra 2.x)

What should I do?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, YCSB does not support Cassandra 3.x yet.

Lets hope YCSB will be releasing new binding for Cassandra 3.x soon.

There is a thread in YCSB issues : https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/issues/166

Comment: Until ycsb is available for 3.x, you can use cassandra-stress for pure Cassandra workloads.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/945), despite Cassandra 3.x is not *officially* supported, you can use the `cassandra-cql` binding.

For instance:

```
/bin/ycsb load cassandra-cql -threads 4 -P workloads/workloada
```

I just tested it on Cassandra 3.11.0 and it works for both `load` and `run`.

That said, the benchmark software to use depends on your test schedule. If you want to benchmark *only* Cassandra, then @gsteiner 's solution might be the best. If you want to benchmark different databases using the same tool to avoid variability, then YCSB is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Cassandra-stress to perform a load/performance test on your Cassandra cluster.  It is very customizable, to the point that you can test distributions with different data models as well as specify how hard you want to push your cluster.

Here is a link to the Datastax documentation for it that goes into how to use the tool in depth.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress_t.html